# why ns doctor android has an issue?

Tags: android, nativescript

```
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 8.1.4 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/core has 8.1.5 version and is up to date.
✖ Component @nativescript/android is not installed.
```

As you can see on the last line my @nativescript/android is not installed.
I did several times all the installation.

Also when I

```
ns run android
```

I have this

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 7):

For start, @nativescript/android needs to be in devDependencies:

Use this to remove from dependencies:

```
npm r @nativescript/android
```

Then this to add to devDependencies:

```
npm i -D @nativescript/android
```

Comment: This seems to be the right answer for me, it wasn't installed in devDependencies as far as the documentation go  I don't see where this is said  ref: https://docs.nativescript.org/understanding-packages.html#nativescript-android

Answer (score 0):

In nativescript 8.2.3, `ns doctor android` was giving the following output:
[ns doctor android output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0FW6.png)

So I installed Android SDK 28 also(33 is also installed still got this issue). Also, the message gives a warning that update for @nativescript/android is available.

Updating @nativescript/android to 8.2.2 from 8.1.1 resolved the issue: 
`npm i @nativescript/android@latest`.

Answer (score 0):

Quit the terminal and reopen, it was give me the same failed result but once I quit and reopen then run `ns doctor android`  everything was correctly setup.